# Function to sum multiple numbers

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python and I started learning to execute function. And I started adding numbers but I could only sum two numbers and if I wanted to sum more, it would require I edit the program. Here's my code

```
def sum(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2

a=5
b=7
c=sum(a,b)
print (c)
```

Now I want to create a function to sum any amount of number you want without Editting the codes. Here was what I did:

```
def sum(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2
a=int(input("what is the number you want to add?: "))
ask="yes"
while(ask=="yes"):
  b=int(input("what is the number you want to add?: "))
  c=sum(a,b)
  a=c
  ask=input("do you want to add another number?: ")
else:
    c=a
    print (c)
```

This worked but i think there should be an easier way to do this with a function... right?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to have an `*args` parameter in your function so that you may take as many inputs more than 1:

```
def summ(num1, *args):
    total = num1
    for num in args:
        total = total + num
    return total
```

What the `*args` means is you can pass through as many arguments as you want:

```
>>> summ(1, 2, 3)
6
>>> summ(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
28
```

`args` is an iterative object: we iterate through it and add each of its numbers to a `total` which we then return.

Comment: `total = total + num` => `total += num`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure :P. I always liked the clarity of `total = total + num`

Comment: so why not `return num1 + sum(args)` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I assumed the OP was learning about writing functions, not about what built-ins existed. Using `sum()` would defeat the purpose of the whole question!

Comment: for lists, don't to `list1 = list1 + list2` because of the quadratic effect. It should be painless for integers, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True, yes. But that's where `list.extend()` comes handy ;)

Comment: Whatever you might might like, not using augmented assignment where it makes sense smells like beginner code (and it might also prevent some optimizations to work as expected).

Answer (score 3):

you can use variable args to accept any number of arguments

```
def my_sum(*args):
    total = 0
    for val in args:
        total += val
    return total
```

You can also use python's in-built sum() to add them:

```
def my_sum(*args):
    return sum(args)

>>> my_sum(1,2,3,4)
10
>>> my_sum(1,5,6,7.8)
19.8
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is Python has a native `sum` function. Use this instead for simple calculations, don't overwrite it with your own.

But to learn more about Python, you may wish to use `functools.reduce`, which applies a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence.

```
from functools import reduce

def mysum(*nums):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, nums)

a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

res = mysum(a,b,c)  # 6
```

This can be incorporated into your logic by building a list which then feeds your function:

```
lst = []

lst.append(int(input("what is the number you want to add?: ")))

ask = "yes"

while ask == "yes":
    lst.append(int(input("what is the number you want to add?: ")))
    ask = input("do you want to add another number?: ")
else:
    res = mysum(*lst)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Why use a module just to add tuple elements!! sum() function can be used here.

Comment: @eiram_mahera, Because this user wants to **learn about Python**. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how to add a different quantity of numbers.
First of all, you can just use a list and built-in function sum:
`sum([1, 2, 3])`

If you wouldn't like to use a list, try to write a custom wrapper on built-in sum function (it is good practice to not override the built-in names):

```
def my_sum(*args):
    return sum(args)

my_sum(1, 2, 3)
```

Also, such usage is possible:

```
my_sum(2) # result is 2
my_sum()  # result is 0
```

But if you want a function, that takes minimum two arguments, try following:

```
def my_sum(num1, num2, *args):
    return num1 + num2 + sum(args)

my_sum(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you an update based on following explanations:

1. I recommend to avoid using the name `sum` for a user-defined function because this is the name of a built-in function of Python, even if it has not caused any trouble (yet) in your case
2. You can use the `sum` built-in function to sum the elements of a list
3. The `else` after the `while` is not useful
4. You can do `a = sum([a,b])` to assign directly `a` without using a temporary variable `c`.

Finally here is my suggestion of code:

```
a = int(input("what is the number you want to add?: "))

ask = "yes"
while (ask == "yes"):
    b = int(input("what is the number you want to add?: "))
    a = sum([a,b])
    ask = input("do you want to add another number?: ")

print (a)
```

Comment: `sum` is NOT a "reserved built-in symbol", it's just a builtin function. If it was a reserved name, trying to use it as an identifier would raise a SyntaxError.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You're right, sir ! I have updated my answer. Thanks a lot.